# "Import error:No module named Cython.Build" while training on Google Cloud ML Engine

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, cython, google-cloud-ml, cythonize

I am trying to train a model on Google Cloud ML Engine with this command. I installed tensorflow with Anaconda.But while I training model , this error appears:

-Import error:No module named Cython.Build
    Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-0eA9cj/pycocotools/

I also added  this line on setup.py :

"REQUIRED_PACKAGES = ['Pillow>=1.0', 'Matplotlib>=2.1', 'Cython>=0.28', 'pycocotools>=2.0.0'
But the problem is not solved,is there any idea to solve this problem?
Thanks in advance...

Comment: were you able to fix it? same issue here

Comment: May you provide some steps in order to reproduce your issue?

Answer (score 0):

Same error for me, This is what worked for me, I added an extra `--packages` to my gcloud command, the packages i've downloaded from pip web repository as zip files and added as the below flag

```
--packages your-folder/Cython-0.28.1.tar.gz,your-folder/pycocotools-2.0.0.tar.gz --packages <your other object-detection and slim packages here>
```